# What does this mean: To be thus is nothing; But to be safely thus

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, shakespeare

This is taken from Shakespeare's Macbeth, and I am having difficulty comprehending what this means. Can someone please put it into normal English, with all explanations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While searching for exact text around those lines (don't remember Macbeth by heart, sorry) stumbled upon this comment:

> to be king is nothing, unless, as king, you are safe.

[Shakespeare-online](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/plays/macbeth/soliloquies/tobe.html)

Comment: and http://library.thinkquest.org/2888/essay.html and http://www.enotes.com/macbeth-text/act-iii-scene-i which state the same

Comment: Thanks for the links. Makes comprehension a whole lot easier.

Comment: @JoseK: I caution wariness of the enotes translations: in this instance the translation is good, but in many places they are just wrong, and some of the most confusing bits they don't bother to translate at all.

Comment: Arguably, to be king without being safe is actually *worse than nothing*. Kings, emporers, etc. are far more likely to be assassinated than commoners.

Answer (score 0):

In modern terms, what matters is to be in a defensible position. It doesn't matter if you are king or head of an organization. You can be toppled unless you are in a defensible position.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that it means that being thus affords you nothing apart from the safety of knowing that you are thus.

Comment: No. In context it is not that at all.